# Generating function for distributing $k$ indistinguishable elements into $n$ distinguishable bins such that each bin has even number of elements.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, generating-functions, balls-in-bins

Generating function for distributing $k$ indistinguishable elements into $n$ distinguishable bins such that each bin has even number of elements.

So for the bins to have exactly even number of elements we assume that $k$ is even and we distribute them into pairs so there are $x = k/2$ indistinguishable elements to insert in $n$ bins. How do I generate the function for the series?

Comment: Do you know the answer if the **even** stipulation wasn't there ?

Comment: Also I assume you are considering no balls in a bin as even. Can you confirm?

Comment: Yes @MathLover no balls in a bin is also even. 
Not really, the even stipulation is just a condition i guess, the result would be similar with or without the stipulation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have $k$ balls and $n$ bins where $k$ is even.

$\sum \limits_1^n b_i = k \,, \, b_i$ is number of balls in each bin and it is even.

If the restriction of **even** was not there, your polynomial for each factor (box) would be $(1 + x + x^2 + .. + x^k)$.

Given the restriction, we only pick even terms.

So the polynomial for each factor would be $(1 + x^2 + x^4 + .. + x^k) \,$ (considering empty box as even)

For $n$ factors, the generating function would be

$g(x) = (1 + x^2 + x^4 + .. + x^k)^n \,$. You have to take the coefficient of term $x^k$.

If you need to take this further,

$g(x) = (1+x^2+x^4+\dots +x^k)^n = \left( \frac{1-x^{k+2}}{1-x^2} \right)^n$

$ = (1-x^{k+2})^n \times (1-x^2)^{-n}$

$= \sum (-1)^i \binom{n}{i} x^{(k+2)i} \times \sum \binom{n + j - 1}{j} x^{2j}$

and take the coefficient of term $x^k$ which means

$(k+2)i + 2j = k \implies i = 0, j = \frac{k}{2} = m \, $ (say).

So we get ${n + m - 1 \choose m}$

**Or you can simply use the infinite geometric series -**

$g(x) = (1 + x^2 + x^4 + .. + ...)^n \, = \frac{1}{(1+x^2)^{n}} = (1+x^2)^{-n}$

$ = \sum \limits_{i=0}^{\infty} {n + i - 1 \choose i} x^{2i}$.

So $, \,i = \frac{k}{2} = m \,$ will be the $x^k$ term and coefficient is
${n + m - 1 \choose m}$.

Comment: So, when we generate function why should we count until k terms instead of k/2 terms?

Comment: Majority of answers about boxes in balls problem are open ended i.e. {1+x^2 +x^4+..................) and are not limited by the number of balls, can you tell me why in this problem we limit it?

Comment: You mean infinite terms that you may see in answers .. $ \, (1 + x^2 + x^4 + ...\infty)$?

Comment: Yes. like https://www.d.umn.edu/~jgreene/Combinatorics/Fall_2015/Notes_on_gen_fcns.pdf for example if you look at the first example.

Comment: It is a choice. I prefer to do this way. Both work and lead to the same answer. If you are used to doing it that way, I can show how it would work here using infinite terms. Let me know if you want me to edit and show that.

Comment: Ahh, Thanks. I was a little confused. I think I understand everything now. But if you showed it that way, It would confirm by method. Also, could you leave the previous answer too. I want to learn to do other questions using the method you used too.

Comment: I just added more details in the end.

Comment: Thank you, this problem is really clear to me now.